# Android Studio 4.0 Layout Inspector isn't working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0

I can't see any updates in Layout Inspector in the new Android studio (4.0).

My app is targeting API 29, and build tools version is `buildToolsVersion '29.0.3'`.

I'm running emulator `Pixel_2_api_29` and my device `MI A3 OS version 10`.

And this is all I can see
[image: layout inspector android studio 4.0]

Comment: Did you update your android gradle plugin to 4.0.0 or higher?

Comment: @orelzion I have the same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: Creating a new emulator fixed it for me.

Comment: @OliverDeLange not yet will try afterward. Thanks!

Comment: I do not even see this Select Process menu. It just does not work.

Comment: I get it working well at the beginning, but didn't know that I need to disable "Filter System-Defined Layers" filter in component tree to see actual views. Maybe this would save somebody time!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In the tools->SDK Manager window, please verify that Layout Inspector Image Server for API 29-30 is installed.

[image]

In case you still face the issue, take a look at the Run window and if you see a dlopen error for a library, add android:extractNativeLibs="true" in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Restart of Android Studio needed after installation of the component to make it work. Though Android Studio did not mention it.

Answer (score 23):

Try to stop current running-app and run with debug mode again (click button "Debug" or press Shift F9) and select your process again. Please see some screenshots below:

1. when error:
   [image]
2. and after stop and run Debug again:
   [image]

Answer (score 18):

Try with
`adb shell settings delete global debug_view_attributes`
and
`adb shell settings delete global debug_view_attributes_application_package`
[image]

Comment: This helped me so that at least AS would show a clue of what was going on

Comment: To others, you'll see this dialog in A/S if you unplug device after "trying" to start Layout Inspector. Daniele didn't just pull these out of no where =)

Comment: Yup, I just had no time to argument the answer, sorry :)

Answer (score 8):

I hit on same issue. And above solutions doesn't work for me. It is resolved by reinstall the app

Comment: Worked for me. Just reinstall the app.

Answer (score 4):

Simply restarting Android Studio seems to solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` isn't in your manifest file.

Comment: I tried all above answers, but none of them works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are unable to view the Flutter Inspector and are seeing something like "Installing DevTools" on a Mac system. You have to add following environment variable.

1. open `~/.bash_profile` or open `$HOME/.zshrc`  (depending upon your file system)
2. Add:

```
Hierarchy Viewer Variable

export ANDROID_HVPROTO=ddm

source ~/.bash_profile
```

3. source `~/.bash_profile` or source `$HOME/.zshrc`

For original answer click here: [Credits](https://forums.bignerdranch.com/t/layout-inspector-not-always-available/12329/3)

Answer (score 0):

In some cases you can resolve this issue to connect device by name instead of connecting by ip.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a different issue than what I see in your screenshot but maybe others have this issue, too.

One can sometime notice, the layout fetch seems to have finished but nothing is shown in the inspector. The reason then seems to be the graphical representation and not the inspector itself.
So if you get something like this:

[image]

**where the zoom controls are visible but somehow no layout is appearing**, try pressing the "Zoom to fit" button. It then re-scales the view which leads to a **redraw**. At least in my configuration for devices **below API 29** (which have no "Live update") this is necessary in order to see something.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

try this:
adb shell setenforce 0 (disable SELinex

Answer (score -1):

In case just like me you stumble on this topic trying to code a Flutter app, I did not manage to make it work either.

Instead, you can use the Flutter Inspector which provides a minimal set of similar functionalities.

Comment: "me too"  does not answer question

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31764007)